# Text Searching and Text Indexing for nested fields in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have a document structure that looks something like this

```
{
  name:
  hobbies:[
    { tag: "food", description: "eating"},
    { tag: "soccer", description: "PL"}
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to achieve Text Indexing only on the `tag` subfield, so that I can attempt text searches with only the `tag` subfield being checked?

Currently I'm trying but it definitely ends up checking the description tag.

```
db.users.createIndex({"hobbies" : "text"})
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get past this using multikey indexes which basically allows us to create an index for every element of the array. And in my case, I used multikey indexes on array fields that contain nested objects which worked liked this

```
db.inventory.createIndex( { "hobbies.tag": "text" } )
```

You can read more about this from the docs here [MongoDB Multikey Index Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)